# How to get all dates between two dates and insert in database?

Tags: php, datetime, foreach

I'm trying to get all dates between two dates and insert all of them in a table. How can I achieve that?

```
    //current date
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

    //find next monday from current date
    $nextMonday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime($currentDate)));   

    //get last day of current year
    $yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('12/31'));

   //get all dates between nextMonday and yearend
   [...]

 foreach ($period as $dateCreated) {
   //insert the dates in db
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_schedule (userId,dateCreated) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt ->bind_param('is',$userid,$dateCreated);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $stmt ->close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_dates_through_range($start, $end, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $range = array();
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');

    $range_end = new DateTime($end);
    $range_end->add($interval);

    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($start), $interval, $range_end);

    foreach($period as $date) {
        $range[] = $date->format($format);
    }

    return $range;
}



$start = '2010-01-01';
$end = '2010-01-05';

$range = get_dates_through_range($start, $end);
// [2010-01-01, 2010-01-02, 2010-01-03 ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, $rep_month, 1, $rep_year);

$lastDay = mktime(0, 0, 0, ($rep_month+1), 0, $rep_year);
```

Use the above code and modify it according to your system , you will get best results.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for me and it works like a charm. Very quick and easy.

```
  //current date
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

    //find next monday from current date
    $nextMonday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday', strtotime($currentDate)));   

    //get last day of current year
    $yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('12/31'));

 //get all dates between nextMonday and yearEnd
    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($nextMonday), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($yearEnd .' +1 day'));

    //iterate over each date
    foreach ($period as $date) {

      //format date
      $dateCreated = $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");

   //insert the dates in db
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_schedule (userId,dateCreated) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt ->bind_param('is',$userid,$dateCreated);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $stmt ->close();
 }
```